# connect in QT issue - no connection?

Tags: qt, connection, signals, signals-slots, slot

I have a custom class derived from QGraphicsPixmapItem. Its called GraphPixmapItemCustom and it's overloaded method is:

```
void GraphPixmapItemCustom::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    QGraphicsPixmapItem::mousePressEvent(event);
    GraphMarkItemCustom *ptr;

    if(event->button() == Qt::RightButton)
    {        
        qDebug("Before emit");
        emit addPoint(QPointF(event->pos().x(), event->pos().y()));
        qDebug("After emit");

        markList.append(new GraphMarkItemCustom(QPointF(event->pos().x(), event->pos().y())));
        ptr = markList.last();
        markGroup->addToGroup(ptr);
        //this->scene()->addItem(ptr);
    }
}
```

the signal is declared at header:

```
signals:
    void addPoint(QPointF position);
```

In main class that has a pointer to object of class GraphPixmapItemCustom called

```
private:
   GraphPixmapItemCustom *pixItemRGB;
```

and in the main class I have a slot called:

```
private slots:
   void pointAdd(QPointF position);
```

In the main class constructor I have a connection:

```
connect(pixItemRGB, SIGNAL(addPoint(QPointF)), this, SLOT(pointAdd(QPointF)));
```

In the slot I have only `qDebug("YUPPY IT ACTUALLY WORKS!");`

But the slot is not beeing fired. Why? I have deleted all moc files and everything that didn't have to be there. So only `.pro`, `.h` and `.cpp` files along with `.ui` forms where neccesary were left.

I have checked most hits at Google. What is the best (I'm not sured - maybe i modified something) that it worked! I remember the working effects of this connection. Help!

Comment: Do "Before emit" and "After emit" get printed on the console ? Does the call to `connect` returns `true` ?

Comment: Did you forget to inherit from QObject, in addition to QGraphicsPixmapItem?

Comment: Yes, they get printed and the connect returns true.

Comment: Yes, i inherit ffrom QObject.

Comment: Did you connect the signal _after_ pixItemRGB was created using "new"?

Comment: OMG, I've not deleted new statement somewhere around code. It works right now. Plz, reply as answer so I could give a point.

Comment: It happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to connect the signal *after* creating the GraphPixmapItemCustom object with the `new` operator.